# How to Find Second Smallest Element

Tags: c++, algorithm

If I enter for example 5 4 3 2 1 it gives 1 and 2 which is correct but if I enter 1 2 3 4 5 it gives 1 and 5 which is false....how to fix this?

This program finds the smallest and second smallest elements through input.

```
#include<iostream>
/*This program finds the smallest and second smallest elements through input*/
using namespace std;
/*This program finds the smallest and second smallest elements through input*/

int main(){
    float input_from_user=0.0, largest=0.0, smallest_num=0.0, runners_up=0.0;
    int count, i;

    cout<<"how many swimming records?"<<endl;
    cin>>count;
    cout<<"enter time: ";
    cin>>input_from_user;
    smallest_num=input_from_user;
    largest=input_from_user;
    for (i=1;i<=count;i++){
        cout<<"enter time: "<<endl;
        cin>>input_from_user;

        /*Compare smallest number with latest input*/
        if (smallest_num>input_from_user){
            runners_up=smallest_num;
            smallest_num=input_from_user;

        }


    }
    cout<<"First:"<<smallest_num<<endl;
    cout<<"Runners up: "<<runners_up<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/*Compare smallest number with latest input*/
if (smallest_num>input_from_user){
    runners_up=smallest_num;
    smallest_num=input_from_user;

}
```

Above code looks as the problem.

If input_from_user is larger than smallest num **but smaller than** runner_up, you should update runner_up.

```
/*Compare smallest number with latest input*/
if (runner_up > input_from_user){
    if(smallest_num > input_from_user) {
        runners_up=smallest_num;
        smallest_num=input_from_user;
    } else runners_up=input_from_user;

}
```

Comment: Initially what do I assign runners_up to?

Comment: Initially runner up is same as smallest_num.

Comment: Or you can initialize runners_up with INT_MAX.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to do the following:

```
vector<float> tms;
for (i=1;i<=count;i++){
        cout<<"enter time: "<<endl;
        cin>>input_from_user;
        tms.push_back(input_from_user);
}
sort(tms.begin(), tms.end());

cout<<"First:"<< tms[0] <<endl;
cout<<"Runners up: "<< tms[1] <<endl;
```

This code only lacks some checks for length before accessing elements.

This isn't optimal because it does sorting on all elements, so there's another method instead of sorting - use additional "set" to have sorted only those elements that have a chance to be at worst the second smallest. In the best case it will just take the first two and do nothing else, in the worst case it will just sort all elements as before.

```
set<float> out;
out.insert(v[0]);
out.insert(v[1]);

for (auto x = v.begin() + 2; x != v.end(); ++x)
{
    auto second = ++out.begin();
    if ( *x < *second )
        out.insert(*x);
}

auto p = out.begin();
cout << "Smallest: " << *p;
++p;
cout << " Second: " << *p << endl;
```

You can always "properly define your algorithm", but the above methods are faster to develop and debug the code.

Comment: You are right that `std::sort` does more work than needed here. This is a case for [`std::partial_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort) instead.